# 0 in integer part of a decimal variable is not displaying

Tags: javascript

Below is the code to display a decimal(18,2) value from database:

```
document.getElementById("knittingcost").innerHTML = "Total Knitting Cost : " + response + " US$/kg";
```

So it displayed as:

```
Total Knitting Cost : .55 US$/kg
```

How to make it display 0.55 US$/kg?

***Update*** - `response` is from Ajax:

```
function fetch_select(val, obj)
{   
    $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url: 'get.php',
            data: {
                    get_option:val, "get_object":obj.id             
                  },
            success: function (response) 
                {           
                    switch (obj.id) {
                        case "Yarn":
                            //code to process yarndivid here    
                            document.getElementById(yarndivid).innerHTML=response;  

                            break;

                        case "Knitting":
                            document.getElementById("knittingcost").innerHTML = "Total Knitting Cost : " + parseFloat(response) + " US$/kg"; 
                        break;

                        case "Dyestuff":
                        break;

                    }
                }

        }); 
}
```

get.php:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['get_option']) or isset($_POST['get_object']))
{

 $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$db, "UID"=>$user, "PWD"=>$pass);
 $dbhandle = sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectionInfo) or die("Couldn’t connect to SQL Server on $server");
 if( $dbhandle === false ) 
    {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

 $id = $_POST['get_option'];
 $objid = $_POST['get_object'];
 $tblname = $sql = "";

 switch ($objid) {
    case "Yarn":
        $tblname = "tblYarnFilament";
        break;
    case "Knitting":
        $tblname = "tblKnitting";
        break;
    case "Coloration":
        $tblname = "tblDyestuff";
        break;
    }

 $sql = "select price2 from ".$tblname." where id = '$id'";

 $find=sqlsrv_query($dbhandle, $sql);

    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($find))
    {   
        echo $row['price2'];
    }
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out, `response` is actually returning this whole section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

.55
```

This `<!DOCTYPE html>` part is actually placed on top of `get.php` document. I thought it doesn't matter!

So I removed that part and parseFloat(response) works perfectly. Thank you everyone for helping.

Lesson learnt, check your variable properly!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript would never display a number as `.55`. So `response` is not a number (and is, presumably, a string). Make it a number:

```
document.getElementById("knittingcost").innerHTML =
    "Total Knitting Cost : " + parseFloat(response) + " US$/kg";
```

Comment: Tha't's weird. Now it displays `Total Knitting Cost : NaN US$/kg`

Comment: Weird indeed. It would really, really help if I didn't have to guess, and you posted exactly what `response` actually was :)

Comment: @yuliana post what `console.log(response);` outputs to the js console

Comment: `console.log(response);` displays `.55`

Comment: How about `console.log(typeof response)`? Also, try adding `dataType: 'text',` as an extra option to `$.ajax`, as currently it's guessing and I have no idea what it guessed, except that it most likely isn't text.

Comment: @Amadan `console.log(typeof response)` displays `string`. Where should I put `dataType: 'text'`?

Comment: That's very, very weird then. If it's a string, and it just contains `".55"`, then it should work, and not give you NaN: `parseFloat(".55")`. Something does not add up, there's no reason you should be getting `NaN`.

Comment: I just found out, `response` is actually returning this whole section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

.55
```

This `<!DOCTYPE html>` part is actually placed on top of `get.php` document. I thought it doesn't matter!

So I removed that part and `parseFloat(response)` works perfectly. Thank you everyone for helping!

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("knittingcost").innerHTML = "Total Knitting Cost : " + parseFloat(response.toString()).toFixed(2)  + " US$/kg";
```

convert it into a string (`.toString()`) and then fix it into 2 decimal (`.toFixed(2)`) places will solved the issues.

Comment: @yuliana can you check this?

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I tried but it displayed NaN. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @yuliana please log response and post i here

Comment: `console.log(response);` displays `.55`

Comment: @ManuVarghese Request you to give a short description of your answer how it solves OP problem?